# How can I send a really large string value to a method?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, string

I have the following method that I am trying to test

```
 global static void updateLoggerError(String msg){
        try {
            Logger.error(msg);
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug('exception caught: ' + ex.getMessage());
            Logger.error(SBAHelperMethods.formatErrorMessage(ex));
        }finally{
            Logger.saveLog();
        }
    }
```

I have a test class that I want to have call this method with a very large string, but it is raising an exception in  the test method itself before it can call updateLoggerError

```
static void test_updateLoggerErrorHugeString(){
        try {
            String s1 = '1000000000000000000';
            String s2 = s1.repeat(1000000);
            
            Test.startTest();
                LoggerRestClassError.updateLoggerError(s2);
            Test.stopTest();
            List<LogEntry__c> logEntryList = [SELECT Id, Message__c FROM LogEntry__c LIMIT 1];
            System.assertNotEquals(0, logEntryList.size());

            if(logEntryList.size() > 0) {
                System.assert(!String.isEmpty(logEntryList[0].Message__c));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.assert(ex.getMessage().length() > 0);
        }        
    }
```

As part of code coverage, how can I pass in a very large string to updateLoggerError so that the program will enter the catch exception block in updateLoggerError? Or if you know another way to enter the catch block with a string of average length that would be helpful too.

Comment: Whenever you're encountering an error or exception, you should include it in your question. At 1 million repetitions of a 19-character (19 byte) string though, that'd put you well over the 6MB heap space limit (not to mention that we couldn't create enough fields to store that much data).

Comment: Testing exceptions can also be tricky business (especially if the class you're trying to test was not designed in a way to specifically make it easy to test). We won't be able to provide much insight without seeing your `Logger` class.

Comment: use dependency injection (underlying logger class should have a MAX_MSGLEN and testmethod can set that value to a small number, like `1`, then log a message of len = 2

Comment: The message text area's size is 131,072 but there's a code before it that truncates the incoming message, so passing in a string 200k chars long doesn't work. Let me know if you have any other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can't exceed the maximum heap size in one string. This is a [governor limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm). Make your string smaller so that it fits in `Limits.getLimitHeapSize` (which will be 6,000,000 in a unit test). Using just a few hundred thousand characters should be sufficient. Also, your unit test shouldn't be using a try-catch block here. It should be able to pass without it.